# POST params empty, what am I doing wrong? HttpURLConnection / Android / Java

Tags: java, android, http, post, httpurlconnection

The code below shows a method, downloadUrl(), that takes a String, "myurl," its parameter.  There are only two possible urls that I ever send to it, and the behavior of the method is different for each.

when myurl = URL1, it uses a GET request and everything works fine.

when myurl = URL2, however, it uses a POST request, and the response from the php page indicates that the post parameters sent with the request were empty.  You can see the line where I set the POST params, so I don't understand why it's sending no params?!

Thanks for any help!
-Adam.

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = null;

        String response = "";

        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();

            // find out if there's a way to incorporate these timeouts into the progress bar
            // and what they mean for shitty network situations


            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // INSERTED QUICK CHECK TO SEE WHICH URL WE ARE LOADING FROM
            // it's important because one is GET, and one is POST


            if (myurl.equals(url2)){

                Log.i(TAG, "dlurl() in async recognizes we are doing pre-call");



                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                String postParams = "?phone=" + phone;

                writer.write(postParams);

                Log.i(TAG, "we're adding " + postParams + "to " + urlObject);

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();


            }

            else {

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.connect();
            }



            // Starts the query

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.i(TAG, "from " + myurl + ", The response code from SERVER is: " + responseCode);

            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            // i guess we look up how to do this





            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                }
            } else {
                response = "from downloadUrl, php page response was not OK: " + responseCode;

            }

            // it's good to close these things?
            is.close();
            conn.disconnect();


            Log.i(TAG, "response is " + response);

            return response;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you dont have conn.connect(); in your if else when it is equal to url2

Comment: Your heading of the question was funny. Expert needed Android/Java. Like giving a job or something!!!  Make it more clear.

Comment: conn.connect() is not the issue... and yeah sorry about the title. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with following code block to send parameters of the POST request.

```
Map<String,String> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("phone", "phone");

StringBuilder postPraamString = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
     if (postPraamString.length() != 0) postPraamString.append('&');
         postPraamString.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
         postPraamString.append('=');
         postPraamString.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
     }
byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
writer.write(postDataBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks! that would have worked, also, but I have found the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the root of the problem...

In the line:

```
String postParams = "?phone=" + phone;
```

The problem was that leading question mark.  The question mark should only be used in GET requests.